# Why is setting enable_indexscan to False not working?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-planner

I'm trying to compare a query's performance with and without an index. I tried setting `enable_indexscan` to `False`, but the query planner still uses an index (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...` shows exactly the same result). What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I'm running:

```
SET enable_indexscan = False;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE indexed_column='some_value';
```

Query plan (irrespective of `enable_indexscan`):

[image]

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* ... not posting the query plans, for a start. Edit your question to add, then comment here.

Comment: Added. The table is partitioned. I've added a date condition to make it shorter (otherwise it would be 92 lines).

Answer (score 4):

`enable_indexscan` only turns off simple index scans.

You should also:

```
SET enable_indexonlyscan = off;
SET enable_bitmapscan = off;
```